# How to translate large text using Google Cloud Translation API in Python?

Tags: python, google-translation-api

I want to translate large text using GoogleCloud Translation API.
I am able to translate short sentences, but I can't translate large text because there is a limit.
The Cloud Translation API is optimized for translation of short requests. The recommended maximum length for each request is 2K code points.
Documentation link:
https://cloud.google.com/translate/quotas

I am thinking to break the large content into small parts and call the API in a loop. But, I don't know the limit for different languages(for example English and Chinese character limit will be different).

What is **2k code points** in the documentation? and how can I calculate the limit for different languages?

Answer (score 0):

You can request for 5k characters per Google translation request. Our product applied 5k characters per request in Google Console platform. You can do that too.

Comment: 5k limit is not enough for me. What if the string contains more than 5k characters?

Comment: As I known, there is no way to improve characters more than 5k, if you product requires a string exceeds 5k characters, then you need to break them up into more pieces.

Comment: How to count the number of characters for different languages?

Comment: Every language is the same length. Just like `str.length == 5000`

Comment: print(len('my name is sachin'))
Output: 17
print(len('我叫萨钦'))
Output: 4

Comment: I guess for a string that more than 5k characters that mean you wanna translate a document, correct? If yes, please use document translation api by google. Document translation can translate characters more than 5k per request.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion

Comment: But, I cannot purchase that API now

Comment: There are many free python packages  you can find. Can I add your facebook and chat with that? https://www.facebook.com/victor.john.92167789/

Comment: This is a free python package you can use for your free translation. https://pypi.org/project/googletrans/

Comment: I have used this package. This package has a limit. We cannot request as many times we want.